# Updating UITableView when retrieving json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an app that has 2 views (table view and details view). I am retrieving data from MySql via PHP file using, the data load in the table fast. I do not know how to update the table! Lets say one of the users update his name in details view, as soon as he goes back to the table view it should changed.

Her is the code:

```
-(void)retrieveVideos {


    NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyWebSite.com/phpfiles/data.php"];

    NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in dataDictionary) {

        ListOfObjects *list = [[ListOfObjects alloc]initWithVTheIndex:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"TheIndex"] timeLineVideoUserName:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoUserName"] timeLineVideoDetails:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoDetails"] timeLineVideoDate:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoDate"] timeLineVideoTime:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoTime"] timeLineVideoLink:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoLink"] timeLineVideoLikes:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"timeLineVideoLikes"] videoImage:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"videoImage"] timeDeviceToken:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"deviceToken"]];


        [self.objectHolderArray addObject:list];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [spinner stopAnimating];
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;

        });
    }


    if(jsonData != nil)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        if (error == nil)
            NSLog(@"%@", result);

    }

}
```

My question is how could I update the table with the new update?

Comment: just [self.tableView reloadData]; will update tableview value

Comment: If i will use that it will duplicate the table. If I have two cells it will be 4 cells and on

Comment: @ user3741700: Remove all array objects before add new Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reload the data of tableview inside dispatch :

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [spinner stopAnimating];
             [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
             [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should notify about the update ,with Delegate or KVO (notification)
after notify about update you should update your data source ( self.objectHolderArray ) with new data, finally you must call :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

or

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, do you mind to edit on my code, I am really new in xcode

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that dataSource and delegate methods is set for tableview.

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

To update UItable you can call tableview's `reloadData` method.

ex: `[self.tableView reloadData]`;